# Facet_wrap / facet_grid any similar function in highcharter?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have the below data frame and plotting has done with ggplot..is there any similar function like `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` in **`highcharter`**

```
df1<-data.frame(
      Year=sample(2016:2018,100,replace = T),
      Month=sample(month.abb,100,replace = T),
      category1=sample(letters[1:6],100,replace = T),
      catergory2=sample(LETTERS[8:16],100,replace = T),
      lic=sample(c("P","F","T"),100,replace = T),
      count=sample(1:1000,100,replace = T)
    )
```

Plot code:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(Year,count,fill=factor(lic))) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack") +
      facet_grid(~category1)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best what I found is this.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year,category1  ,lic) %>% 
  summarise(count=sum(count)) 
map(unique(df2$category1), function(x){
  df2 %>% filter(category1 == x) %>% 
    hchart(., "column", hcaes(x = Year, y = count, group = lic),showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
    hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>% 
    hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>% 
    hc_title(text = x) %>% 
    hc_yAxis(title = list(text = ""))
  }) %>% 
  hw_grid(rowheight = 150) %>% htmltools::browsable()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update and i have another prob..can u let me know any idea : i need to plot week,month on x axis and category1 will be one group and facets will be category2..is it possible to easily in ggplot?

Comment: Is it possible to export it? I've tried using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` and it didn't work